# Devtools elements tab very slow

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge

for about 2 weeks the devtools in both chrome and edge are very slow while being in the elements tab. Other tabs are fine. My not up to date chromium works flawlessly.

It feels like stutter or lag. As if the pc is being hammered really hard.
I'm using edge 86.0.622.51 and chrome 86.0.4240.111 on mac catalina.

Launching the Browser without any extensions doesn't help.

Ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in devtools, which you can report on https://crbug.com.

Comment: I tried to test the issue on MAC Catalina OS with the MS Edge version 86.0.622.43 and also tested with the Google Chrome browser. I found that the Elements tab works fine. There is no lag while locating the elements on a page. The same result I got with the Google Chrome browser. I suggest you make a test with the latest updates of the Edge browser and see whether it fixes the issue. If the issue persists try to reinstall the Edge browser and see whether it helps to fix this issue. Let us know about your test results.